# Improper sorting?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a cell in MySql table `page_order`. When I add a new line using php form, nothing is written to this cell.
I have using jQuery `sortable` with a record in the database, when we move the items, then this cell `page_order` is updated.

Here is part of my code

```
 <?php
                        include 'dbs.php';
                        $db = new DB();
                        $users = $db->getRows('artists',array('order_by'=>'page_order ASC'));

                        if(!empty($users)): $count = 0; foreach($users as $user): $count++;
                    ?>
                <?php $idd = $_GET['id']; ?>
               <?php if(($user['interline'] == NULL) && $user['event_id'] == $idd){ ?>


    <div class="action-box" id="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>">
            <div class="action-box-count">
                 <div class="count-number"><?php echo $count; ?></div>
                 <div class="count-time">
                     <div class="count-time-top">15:37 <span>21</span></div>
                     <div class="count-time-bottom">15:50 <span>29</span></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
           <div class="action-box-info">
              <p class="user-name"><?php echo $user['fullname']; ?></p>
              <p class="user-info"><?php echo $user['artist1']; ?></p>
              <p class="user-info"><?php echo $user['artist2']; ?></p>
            </div>
          </div>

     <?php } ?>
     <?php if(($user['interline'] != NULL) && $user['event_id'] == $idd){ ?>



    <div class="action-box action-end" id="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>">
              <div class="action-box-count">
                 <div class="count-number"><?php echo $count; ?></div>
             </div>  
            <div class="action-box-info">
              <div class="text-center"><?php echo $user['interline']; ?></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      <?php } ?>


  <?php endforeach; else: ?>
                    <tr><td colspan="5">Not found......</td></tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>

   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addLink" onclick="javascript:$('#openForm').toggle();"><div class="action-box action-add"></div></a>
   <?php  
$idint = $_GET[id];
echo "<a class='action-box action-add-small' href=\"interline.php?idi=".$idint."\"><div class='text-center'><span class='icon'>Interline</span></div> </a>";

?>


   <input type="hidden" name="page_order_list" id="page_order_list" />
</div>
</div>
```

Then I use ajax to send a request in file when I process:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_POST["page_id_array"]); $i++)
{
 $query = "
 UPDATE artists 
 SET page_order = '".$i."' 
 WHERE id = '".$_POST["page_id_array"][$i]."'";
 mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#order_list" ).sortable({
  placeholder : "ui-state-highlight",
  update  : function(event, ui)
  {
   var page_id_array = new Array();
   $('#order_list div').each(function(){
    page_id_array.push($(this).attr("id"));
   });
   $.ajax({
    url:"order.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{page_id_array:page_id_array},
    success:function(data)
    {
     alert(data);
    }
   });
  }
 });


});
```

the problem is:
1. Wrong step with writing to db, i.e. is not 1,2,3,4,5, but as follows: 10,22,27,30,33
2. And the second problem is that when I check `<?php if(($user['interline'] != NULL)` to output another string - sorting and numbers behave generally as horrible.

Tell me please how to figure it out?

Comment: A little update:
With:

`if(($user['interline'] == NULL) && $user['event_id'] == $idd){  } 
     if(($user['interline'] != NULL) && $user['event_id'] == $idd){    }` 

from the beginning, almost everything is good (starts with 5 only, and far 6,7,8,9, ..) but the sorting is chaotic

With:

`if(($user['interline'] == NULL) && $user['event_id'] == $idd){ }` 

with a step of chaos (10, 12, 17, 27, 30, ...) but the sorting is correct

Comment: Without the ajax call, it's hard to guess what's going on

Comment: Also, the amount of divs in the two `if` statements don't seem to add up, which is probably what's causing the sorting issues

Comment: Added Ajax code. Yes, I understand about the conflict divs and two `if`, I can not understand how to solve it

Comment: In the else after your foreach, you are adding a <tr> which would imply you are in a <table> or <tbody> element. Div are not supposed to be there, use table rows and table cells.

Comment: Thank you about tr, fixed into div.

Comment: If someone needs to be, I solved my question:
1. see, that normally worked order.php
2.  this part `<?php echo $count; ?>` need to replace with `<?php echo $user['page_order']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

The gaps you see are coming from this part:

```
$('#order_list div').each(function(){
    page_id_array.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

You are selecting ALL divs inside `#order_list`. This fills your array with empty values for all the divs that do not have ID... Since you are causing gaps in the index, that results to an ordered list with gaps. (Not that it really matters anyways, since they are just to order...)

```
$('#order_list div.action-box').each(function(){
    page_id_array.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Here, targeting just the action-box (which seems to be holding the ID) will make sure you iterate on just the right divs.

Comment: I understand what you're talking about. This method doesn't want to work